# Which Syntax highlighting plugin is used by bulma css framework?

Tags: html, css, bulma

can someone tell me what is the code highlighter plugin that [bulma.io](http://bulma.io/documentation/form/input/) used ? I already checked all sources and scripts and I can't figure out the plugin's name.

here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post that question at their support, it is off-topic here at SO

Answer (score -1):

Looks like they used something self-made.

Comment: Meta-question: Generally, should an answer be downvoted simply because the OP is considered off-topic? Even if the answer is useful?